# Run maven:install will copy more jars to WEB-INF/lib than i expect

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp, m2e

Eclipse Indigo; m2e 1.1.0; Maven integration for WTP 0.15.3; Maven 3.0.4

My web project has some dependency projects in the same workspace. All projects are installed. When i run maven install, except to see all dependencies in WEB-INF/lib.

When i run maven install plugin or maven war plugin, the WEB-INF/lib will be filled with dependencies, but they are a lot more than i expected, from the "dependency Hierarchy" or "Effective POM" view of the POM file, or from Maven dependencies in classpath view, i can not find the dependencies.

Run **Maven->update projects** does not help.

So where these dependencies come from or where should i start to debug?

**EDIT**
Previously my project has a large dependency tree(100+ jars), some of them are not needed, so i decided to remove them. My project depends on a common project, which has some not needed dependencies, i remove them from POM dependencies and run maven install for the whole projects dependency tree, success. then i run maven install on my project, it should not include the jars i removed from the common project, but, unfortunately they are there in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Maybe you should add a list of expected and actual jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I delete the whole project and import from remote, run maven-install, it worked. Still have no idea why it not work before even after i run "maven clean install" on all dependency projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know where your dependencies are coming from, run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

from the command line. This shows how transitive dependencies are pulled in from your declared dependencies. 
You can also run:

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

to see if you can remove any unused dependencies to lessen the number of JARs packaged.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Run mvn dependency:tree, the result  was just as i saw from the Eclipse POM view--no extra jars. What i'd like to know is, why it copied the extra jars to WEB-INF/lib that did not in the dependency tree.